# Upload or move image into the folder through javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Thanks in Advance
i am using the code below
i am calling this function onchange event of browse(input type=file multiple=multiple id=uploadimage)
how should i upload image in the tmp folder so that i can preview in the code below

```
function test (){
    var table = document.getElementById("rounded-corner1");
    var path  = "pz_serveroriginal/tmp/";
    var files = document.getElementById("uploadimage").files;
    table.innerHTML = "<tr><th>File Name</th><th>Image Preview</th><th>Delete</th></tr>";

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){ 
        table.innerHTML += "<tr>";
        table.innerHTML += "<td>"+ files[i].name +"</td>";
        table.innerHTML += "<td><a target=_blank href="+ path + files[i].name +" >"+ files[i].name +"<div id=somediv alt=your image ></div></a></td>";
        table.innerHTML += "<td><a href=# class=delbutton id=" + i + "><img title=Delete src=images/Delete.png ></a></td>";
        table.innerHTML += "</tr>";
        document.f2.image.src = files[i].name;
    }

}
```

Comment: What browser support do you require?

Comment: @PatsyIssa in all the browsers except I.E

Comment: Can you add your form submission function as well ? Are you using ajax ?